# How is correct to run php consumer-script for rabbitmq?

Tags: php, linux, rabbitmq, debian, daemon

I need help.

I have a few tasks their need to run after record added to DB. For example: compressing uploaded pictures. For doing it, I using RabbitMQ.

I have separate script, it's fully equal this example, except logic in process_message function: 
https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php.

As I understand this long-life running script, I run it in Linux by using command:

`nohup php amqp_consumer.php production &`

But sometimes this task is crashing. And I can't control it. I need to have methods to restart this task automatically.

Could your please give me advice how you run consumer? How you control it and restart? Thank you.

Comment: Use a process manager like Supervisor, it automatically restarts the process when a job fails.

Comment: I second the supervisord ... besides that I use this thing to sit in background (since PHP isn't best for bg process): https://github.com/ricbra/rabbitmq-cli-consumer

Answer (score 1):

Thank all for help! I start using `supervisord` and using cron to restart task four time in day.